# How to do blocking subscribe using bunny RabbitMQ client?

Tags: ruby, jruby, rabbitmq, message-queue

In java RabbitMQ client I can do (code in ruby):

```
 consumer = QueueingConsumer.new(channel);
 channel.basicConsume(queue_name, true, consumer);
 consumer.nextDelivery.getBody
```

And then third line blocks thread until message comes. But how to achieve it in Bunny client?
I can only use block:

```
channel.queue('').bind(@x, :routing_key => rk).subscribe(block: true) do |_, _, payload|
  # do something
end
```

or non blocking pop:

```
delivery_info, properties, payload = q.pop
```

**Is there a way to achieve it like in jruby client using Bunny?** The reason I want is that after receiving a message I would like to continue job in my current context.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Bunny does synchronous requests only. It's always blocking so you can make a request, your code will wait, get its response, then you continue.

Comment: You're passing `:block => true` so the calling thread is blocked until the message arrives. Are you expecting something different?

Comment: @RobHarrop I can only block calling thread using block of code, but I would like to access payload directly, how it is done by `consumer.nextDelivery.getBody` in java client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `subscribe` is blocking due to passing `:block => true`. If you need to access the payload outside of the block, you can take advantage of Ruby's scoping rules:

```
the_payload = nil
queue = channel.queue('').bind(@x, :routing_key => rk)
queue.subscribe(block: true) do |delivery_info, _, payload|
  the_payload = payload
  channel.consumers[delivery_info.consumer_tag].cancel
end
# the_payload is now the one received in the block!
```

Comment: Does
`channel.consumers[delivery_info.consumer_tag].cancel`
cancels the subscribe block and unblock the tread?

My current solution is:

    queue = channel.queue('').bind(@x, :routing_key => rk)
    msg = nil
    while !msg do
        queue = queue.pop[2]
    end

Answer (score 1):

Rob Harrop's answer does cancel the queue, but it didn't end the block for me. The following does both using a ruby `Queue`

```
require "thread"

unblock = Queue.new # Ruby Queue, not Bunny::Queue
queue = channel.queue('').bind(@x, :routing_key => rk)
consumer = queue.subscribe do |delivery_info, properties, body|
  # do something
  result = determine_if_it_is_time_to_move_on
  unblock.enq true if result
end

unblock.deq # block until a message is enqueued in the ruby Queue
consumer.cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to receive a single message from a queue. Bunny's `Queue#pop` is non-blocking and does not have an option to wait. I also needed to support a timeout, and I ended up implementing this:

```
require "thread"

mutex = Mutex.new
var = ConditionVariable.new
payload = nil
consumer = queue.subscribe(block: false) do |_, _, x_payload|
  mutex.synchronize do
    payload = x_payload
    var.signal
  end
end

mutex.synchronize do
  deadline = Time.now + 10
  while payload.nil? && (remaining = deadline - Time.now) > 0
    var.wait(mutex, remaining)
  end
end

consumer.cancel
raise "timed out waiting for response" if payload.blank?
```

Inspired in part by https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/28/queue-pop-with-timeout-fixed/

This code has not been battle-tested. It works on staging with a single message. It may not work at scale. I was going to hide all of this complexity in a monkey-patch to `Bunny::Queue`. Callers would have seen a simple `blocking_pop(timeout:)` API.